# Making a GUI is hard

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have made these 2 sketches that represents what im trying to make. When I compile the code I want a frame with 1 button that says "start", to appear (aka sketch 1). When I click start the start button goes away and a new button appears that says "pick up" and 3 panels that has a starter value of 0. When you click on the button, 1 of the 3 panels randomly picked will get +1 in value and the value in the panel will update and show the total value in that panel (SKETCH 2).

I hope you understand the idea, and I would like to know if this Is possible first ofc. And if you have an idea of where I could start, I would love to hear it (:

**SKETCH 1**
[image: Sketch 1]
**SKETCH 2**

[image: Sketch 2]

Comment: You may want to Box Sizer between button and panel.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews How?? I think I might be trying to rn but I can't seem to find out how....

Comment: I can't tell you how to code, because I use `wxFrameBuilder` to organize my GUI and have it generate the code.  Search the internet for "C++ wxWidgets example wxPanel wxSizer wsButton"

Comment: @user13170084, BTW, you need to be really familiar with the language first. wxWidgets is NOT a library for beginners. Know the tools and then come back and use them with the specific things you intend them to be used. BTW2, wxWidgets is NOT a tool to learn C++. You have a school for that.

Comment: @user13170084 StackOverflow is a website designed to act as a Q and A repository, so others can search for their questions and find similar or identical ones with an answer. Do not edit your question to "I got an answer from X". If you want to thank the person, you may do that in a comment but only on your own answer, otherwise it is probably considered spam.

Comment: WxWidgets is libaray that should not be used anymore. It's outdated and not really maintained for at least a decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user13170084,

You don't need to scale anything!!

In you wxFrame create a function that will what you want.

Bind wxEVT_BUTTON to the wxButton click and wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN to the panel. There call that function.

Now - this will be one weird design. You may need to rethink what you want to do.

```
void MyFrame::Handler()
{
}

MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
    panel = new wxPanel();
    button = new wxButton();
    panel->Bind( wxEVT_LEFT_CLICK, &MyFrame::OnClick, this );
    button->Bind( wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::OnButton, this );
}

void MyFrame::OnClick()
{
    Handler();
}

void MyFrame::OnButton()
{
    Handler();
}
```

Comment: If you put a wxButton on a wxSizer, the button can be made to expand to the boundaries of the sizer.

Comment: Hmm kinda hard to understand haha....

Comment: @user13170084, do you want me to write a template code for you?

Comment: @user13170084, I updated my answer with some updated code. But I think you can just drop the wxEVT_BUTTON altogether. Try it both ways. Still this design is very weird, especially since you mentioned you want 2 buttons on the frame...

Comment: um i mean 1 button on each of the 2 panels

Comment: @Igor but yes i would love a template

Comment: @Igor i dont see the updated code btw.

Comment: @user13170084, code added, sorry for the confusion. But you really need to rethink you design and maybe drop the ideqa of panel/button relationship. There is absolutely no need for that.

Comment: @user13170084, BYW, I strongly suspect you are doing smth wrong in terms of the design...

Comment: @user13170084, please accept/upvote the answer if it soves the problem/its helpful. But I do hope you re-thought the design and disregard this alltogether... ;-)

Comment: @Igor thansk mate ill loook into it, btw would you be able to give me a template or is it the code you added?

Comment: @user13170084, the code I added in the answer is the template. Justuse appropriate signatures and put some code in. But as said - this design is really weird. Can you update the OP with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey, @Igor  i know its a bit wird to ask this but would you like to somehow supervise or like mabye give me a little insight on how you would start off, if you had to make an idea of mine i have for a GUI?? (its about c++ and wxwidgets ofc).

Comment: @user13170084, I can help with the design but I don't have time to write a code for you. What exactly do you want to make?

Comment: @Igor I completely understand and I don't expect for you to write the code at all. All im looking for is some guidance :). BTW I edited the asked problem up top with what im trying to do.

Comment: @user13170084, this is pretty straightforward and easy to do. Take a look at wizard sample.